# dust-me error : content-type is not CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

When push clear button in Firefox Dust-me an error appears whit this content:

Cannot process stylesheet [Content-type is not CSS]

note:
1-It show unused and used css correctly. I cant remove it.
2-when i test it for some other pages it work true.
3-My html file and css atached[image]

see codes too :
My html File: http://www.4shared.com/document/TfMTKYvyba/arminshop_home.html
Mys CSS File:http://www.4shared.com/document/me6CJNbOce/new.html

Comment: Can you try including your HTML and CSS again? It's not in the question or attached.

Comment: I assume you're using "Dust-Me Selectors" plugin... what version are you using? (there was a time when it wasn't updated and you could get it somewhere else.. just to make sure you're not using a bugged version)

Comment: Firefox was 35.0.1 and i update to 36 and  Dust-Me Selectors 4.1

Comment: Dear friends i try it trough a webserver and it work but it is so time consuming.

Answer (score 6):

Is the website hosted in a server? otherwise it won't work. I had the same problem.

Comment: Great! I have to host it in IIS.

Comment: Finally got it working.  Didn't work for a simple html page and a css file with 20,000 lines in it.  It outputted lots of undefined's.